# Can we use SSD with HSQLDB for durable trust of not losing performance or space?

Tags: hsqldb

I have a small DB of 4 tables and only one of the table is storing BLOBS. I am afraid if at some point the space exhausts due to large (GBs sized) BLOBS. I also dont want to perform clean operation rather to retain data as much as possible, no matter how old it is... What should be the vision of my in-process mode HSQLDB on a Linux Machine with RAM 128GB, with storage size (of that specific drive on which HSQLDB and my app is deployed) 300 GB?

Answer (score 0):

Modern server-grade SSD's are considered reliable for durable storage of data. HSQLDB performs a lot faster with the database on SSD as opposed to magnetic disk.

However, it is important to backup the database regularly to avoid major data loss in case of a disk hardware failure.

The space for BLOBs is allocated as you insert new rows containing BLOBs. You can provision the disk space based on your usage estimates.